# Textview.text change example

Tags: android, textview

I have 2 layouts. First layout has 2 textviews. And second layout has 1 button. I want to do when i pres buton textviews.text change. But i get null error about textviews.

textviews on musicactivity, button on homeactivity.

my first activity class --> homeactivity,secon activity class --> Musicactivity,textview-->ad1,textview-->ad2,textviews on musiclayouts,Button on homeactivity.

```
    public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    TextView ad1;
    TextView ad2;
    private MusicActivity music;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);


        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            ad1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            ad2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                {           
                    ad1.setText(null);
                    ad2.setText(null);
                }

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Show your code here...........

Comment: where does the error occur, on `HomeActivity` or `MusicActivity` ?

Comment: Error on homeactivity when i press button. Nullexception error. My textviews get null point.

Comment: why do you set your text views to null?

Comment: I want to set like "". So i give null value

Comment: that's incorrect, you should use `setText("")`

Comment: I used it now but again get same error

Comment: could you post your logcat output ?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.tablayout.HomeActivity.onClick(HomeActivity.java:40)

Comment: I didnt write here because its works normal.Edit my codes

Comment: I agree with mangusta. Setting the text of a TextView to null looks a bit wonky. In Java, null strings are not the same thing as in some other languages. In your code, it might be working, but using that approach in other situations, will eventually cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted is for line 40, which is doing a close of v1. I don't know what a veritabani is, but it appears that error is happening there. I suspect the rest of the error trace might say more.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You can't get the textViews if they are not in the layout. You say yourself they are not in the layout. You have to pass the values you want to set to the new activity (musicActivity) via an Intent. Then in musicActivity's you can get the textViews, you have the values, you set them.